# Use the output of a command as input of the next command

Tags: linux, bash

So I call this PHP script from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/bims/index.php "projects/output"
```

and its output is:

```
file1 file2 file3
```

What I would like to do is get this output and feed to the "rm" command but I think im not doing it right:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/bims/index.php "projects/output" | rm
```

My goal is to delete whatever file names the PHP script outputs. What should be the proper way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361329/how-to-use-the-output-of-a-command-as-an-input-to-other-program-in-linux which is a really basic question about pipes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/bims/index.php "projects/output" | xargs rm
```

Comment: man xargs: "xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input". You should read that manual page ;)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution:

```
rm `/usr/bin/php /var/www/bims/index.php "projects/output"`
```

What is between the backticks (`` `...` ``) is run as a command, and the output is passed as argument to `rm`.

Comment: xargs is slightly better: it can handle output that is too long for the maximum command line length by running `rm` more than once.

Comment: I didn't say *better*. I said *simple* :).

Comment: note: might not work if the Php script produce files with spaces

Comment: Wikipedia has some interesting examples, KISSly explained, regarding files with spaces, lines, etc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs.

Comment: simple and elegant!

Comment: Even in 2010 the `$(command substitution)` syntax was recommended over backticks since many, many, many years.

Answer (score 3):

you can try `xargs`

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/bims/index.php "projects/output" | xargs rm
```

or just simply use a loop

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/bims/index.php "projects/output" | while read -r out
do
  rm $out
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could help>>

grep -n "searchstring" filename | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " };{print $1}'