# How to use the output of a command as an input to other program in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ash

I have a program running on linux

This program take its input from the stdin

So I can launch it with input file in this way

```
myprogram < file
```

in order to avoid typing input to the program

Now I want that the program take the input from a command output. something like that

```
myprogram < anycommand
```

but this does not work because it's expecting a file and not a command.

How I can make it work? Are there a shell syntax to make it work?

Note: I can not use pipe like `anycommand | myprogram`

Comment: Best to explain why can't you use `anycmd| myprog`? That is a core pattern of all Unix-like programs. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

normally (IMHO) *myprogram* does not know anything about *file*. The bash starts *myprogram* and reads the file, and writes the content of *file* to the stdin of *myprogram*. 
So *myprogram* should not know that his stdin is a file.
So, *anycommand | myprogram* must work.

If it doesn't work with ash, maybe you can make a named pipe (mkfifo /tmp/testpipe)
Now you can start your program with `myprogram < /tmp/testpipe` and you can write your input to */tmp/testpipe*

Answer (score 2):

On my Linux system, `ash` is a symbolic link to `dash` and that handles pipes just fine:

```
pax> ls -ld $(which ash)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar  1  2012 /bin/ash -> dash

pax> ash

$ echo hello | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
HELLO
```

So I'd give the `anycommand | myprogram` another shot just in case.

If your `ash` has *no* piping capability, you can always revert to using temporary files, provided `anycommand` isn't a long-lived process that you need to handle the output of in an incremental fashion:

```
anycommand >/tmp/tempfile
myprogram </tmp/tempfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like this:

```
myprogram < <(anycommand)
```

This is called [**process substitution**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried your command but it returns the following error: `-ash: syntax error: unexpected redirection`

Comment: I am not sure if `ash` supports this, can you use `bash`?

Comment: I don't have a way to test it in `ash` since I don't have it. Is there any online tester for this?

Comment: I looked at http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ash.htm and didn't find any process substitution. Did you try: `anycommand|myprogram`? What error you got?